# $this->request->data change after validations errors cakephp

Tags: cakephp, validationerror

I have trouble with some validation errors in my Model. I lost much of my datas when an error is occured. I see that $this->request->data change like as he will be treated in the controller. But when an error occurs, I'm redirect to the view and i don't have the good "$this->request->data to display my view.

Please do you any solution?

Edit: With code from Model file. I add //BUG HERE to notify where $this->data->request is not re-set.

class Event extends AppModel {

```
    public $hasMany = 'CategoryOptionEventEvent';
    public $hasOne = array(
    'CategoryVehicleEvent' =>
        array(
            //'className' => 'Event',
            'joinTable' => 'category_vehicle_events',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => ''
        ),
    );
    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
        'description' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
        //'date' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
        'hour' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
        'street_number' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
        'street_name' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
        'postal_code' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
        'city' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
        //BUG HERE
        'vehicle_minimum' => array(
            'rule1' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
            ),
            'rule2' => array(
            'rule' => array('comparisonWithField', '<=', 'vehicle_maximum'),
            'message' => 'Le nombre de véhicule minimum doit être inférieur ou égal au nombre de véhicule max.'
        )
    ),
    'vehicle_maximum' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
    'vehicle_price' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
    'attendent_price' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
    'attendent_maximum' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
    'is_visible' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
    //Validation date
    //BUG HERE
    'date' => array(
            'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
            'message' => 'Entrez une date correcte !')
    );
```

Edit Resolved :
I resolved my issue with Validating Data from the Controller

```
if($this->Event->validates()){
}
else{
$this->request->data = $this->Event->findById($id);
}
```

Thanks to have a look on my trouble.

Comment: It's still a little unclear to me what you are asking for... can you post a code example?

Comment: If you fail validation and return back to the view,then you need to re-set `$this->request->data` as you would have done when the view was rendered initially. If that's not what your asking, post some code to clarify

Comment: Yes, i need to re-set $this->request->data but I don't see where can I reset the variable? :/